# How to keep the latest state of Angular components?

Tags: angular

I have several others inserted in the main component:

```
<app-tools * ngIf = "type === 'A'"> </app-tools>
<app-history * ngIf = "type === 'B'> </app-history>
<app-layers * ngIf = "type === 'C'> </app-layers>
<app-objects * ngIf = "type === 'D'> </app-objects>
```

All of them are activated by the condition `*ngif`

When the user activates the `<app-history> </<app-history>` component and does some work in it, after it leaves the component, switching to another one.

Then, upon returning to the   component, it is initialized again.

How to save the last state in the visited Angular component without using `[hidden]`, because in this case a lot of memory is allocated for loading unclaimed components?

Comment: probably using services, as if you use `*ngIf` it will remove from the DOM so didn't able to maintain state.

Comment: Certantly i is, but I need solution

Comment: Rxjs is Your friend here Just get latest state when component recreated. thats way you can achieve state fully in angular.

Comment: Could you explan more about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Complete Working Demo on** [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uoimrh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontainer%2Fcontainer.component.html)

**Here, simple** you can use `shared singleton service` with `@Input()` and `@Ouput()` parent child component architecture. I am taking consideration of history component only.
First You have one 1. Container Component which is parent of component used for communicating to service only. and rest all are child component which are only receiving and sending input and output using `@Input()` and `@Output()`.

**HTML is of Container Component is**...

```
   <div class="form-group col-2 m-1 card d-flex alert-secondary  justify-content-around">
     <div class="card-body justify-content-around d-flex">
       <input class="form-check-input" #b [(ngModel)]= "ab" type="checkbox" id="b"> 
       <label for="b"> B </label>
   </div>

  <div class="card m-1  col-12 col-md-3 alert-secondary " *ngIf="b.checked">
     <app-history class="card-body" [stateHistory]="getHistoryState()" 
           (stateUpdate)="historyStateUpdate($event)" >
     </app-history>
  </div>
```

In `<app-history>` class we have one `[stateHistory]` as aInput and one `(stateUpdaate)` as a Output.

**Your containerComponent.ts**

In this component class we inject state-service using DI of angular.

```
  constructor(private stateService: StateService) { }

getHistoryState(){
  return this.stateService.historyState;
}

historyStateUpdate(event){ 
  this.stateService.historyState = event;
  this.saved = true;
  this.saveNotification();
}
saveNotification(){
  setTimeout(() => {
     this.saved = false;
  }, 2000);
}
```

Further you can scale here to use rxjs as per your required need.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a state store of some kind to persist the data changes. NgRx is one solution. If you don’t want to use another library you can create your own state service where you would have behavior subjects defined in the service. When you make a change within the tab, you would execute the next method on the subject variable, passing in the data changes as the parameter to the method call. Within the component, you can can access the current value of the subject by ‘.value’ on the subject. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[hide]** property of angular instead of *ngIf. Doing so you are keeping all the components in the dom but displaying only the current active component by which you will not lose the component state even if it is not displayed.

```
<app-tools   [hide] = "type !== 'A'"> </app-tools>
<app-history [hide] = "type !== 'B'> </app-history>
<app-layers  [hide] = "type !== 'C'> </app-layers>
<app-objects [hide] = "type !== 'D'> </app-objects>
```

Comment: Hidden is mean all constructors of components will be loaded, but I dont need it

Comment: You have to mention that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use two way data-binding and have your state passed through the parent of app-history or whatever.
Just be careful about naming your input and output properties of childComponent i.e it should always have "Change" appended to its output corresponding property. Something like:

```
@Input() x;
@Output() xChange = new EventEmitter();
```

---

```
<div>
 <app-history *ngIf = "type === 'B'" [(myState)]="historyState"></app-history> 
</div>

AppHistoryComponent {
@Input() myState;
@Output() myStateChange = new EventEmitter();

changeMyState(newState) {
 this.myStateChange.emit(newState);
}
}
```

---

In this way you will always have your state their in your ParentComponent's `historyState` property

Comment: I mean when ngIf works it calls ngOnInit again, that initializes whole component again. But I need to get prev statement

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own class that implements [`RouteReuseStrategy`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy). It caches all or chosen components and prevents them from being re-created from scratch again and again. As an example you may have a look at [`AppRouteReuseStrategy`](https://github.com/centeractive/koia/blob/master/src/app/app-route-reuse-strategy.ts).

> Please note that the class needs to be registered as a provider in
>   `app.module.ts`.

```
providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: AppRouteReuseStrategy },
```

Comment: I dont use routing in prject, it has main component with some inside