# Initialize component only once when attaching to a portal

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I need to attach and detach an instance of a set of components from a portal dynamically without reinitializing it every time I attach as it degrades the performance of the application a lot.

```
portal = new ComponentPortal(MyComponent);
this.portalHost = new DomPortalHost(
      this.elementRef.nativeElement,
      this.componentFactoryResolver,
      this.appRef,
      this.injector
    );

const componentRef = this.portalHost.attach(this.portal);
componentRef.instance.myInput = data;
componentRef.instance.myOutput.subscribe(...);
componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

This is the way that is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47469844/angular-cdk-how-to-set-inputs-in-a-componentportal). But every time the component is reattached it will reinitialize.

Comment: Maybe you can use `RouteReuseStrategy` as explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60166812/2358409

Comment: the most simple way is creating a module for each component and lazy loading them.

Comment: I am not sure if the RouteReuseStrategy will work as the component that I am rendering at a time is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll be better off using a Component Factory in order to load components at runtime:

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Still wouldn't I have to destroy the component every I hide it and also this is no help if I want to add a placeholder component to show when the dynamic component is not visible.

Comment: Have you tried making the component singleton, and then attaching its singleton instance?

Comment: I need to attach a component dynamically so am looking for a solution where I don't have to change any implementation inside the component